How to do Proof of Authority?
Hey I would like to make a test net with a closed validator set, specified in the genesis config. Does Solana support proof of authority? Or is there another way to accomplish this?
Thanks

Could you give more information on what Proof of Authority is and what you're expecting on Solana with Proof of Authority?

sorry by proof of authority I mean a fixed validator set from genesis. So a new validator can't join by staking.

Solana was designed to be an open and permissionless blockchain, so there's no native way to start a closed network.
Typically, you would do this at the economic level, by controlling delegations to validators on the network.
If you want a more hammer-style approach though, you could modify the vote program's "initialize" instruction, making it impossible at the protocol level for certain participants to create a vote account used for consensus.
You can include a list of account keys that are allowed to create vote accounts, and prohibit others from doing it, or just disable the instruction altogether.
You can find the source code at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/0168e0ab69a631d5998507924debaba1caa566ba/programs/vote/src/vote_processor.rs#L71 and just modify it to no-op.
